# Pod installation Failed || Permission for Pod installaion || React native || Mac M1

Tags: react-native

I am developing my new project on Mac M1 machine. Everything is working fine on android, but I am unable to install pod for ios. Went through all the possible installations. Still it throws strange error.

When I run sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi as mentioned in the official doc, I am getting the below error msg.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

And in some cases I got found this when I install sudo gem install cocoapods.

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: 
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/pod: line 2: 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: Undefined error: 0
```

No idea about What went wrong.

Share your thoughts here. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the permission issue try sudo pod-install --allow-root command

and then give read write permission to the folder

Step to give read write permission :

1. right click on folder
2. getinfo
3. click lock button and enter your
4. then give r/w permission
5. then left corner in getinfo popup press the three dot
6. apply to all enclosed item and try after that

Comment: 1. sudo pod-install --allow-root ==> sudo: pod-install: command not found
2. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi ==> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
3. arch -x86_64 pod install ==> /opt/homebrew/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/pod: line 2: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: Undefined error: 0